# webpage not responding recover webpage ie11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

In IE11 I am getting a message webpage not responding with a button to recover webpage. After an investigation on this I came to know that it may be due to addons or due to presence of lot of temporary files and corrupted files in internet cache folder. The fix would be like disable addons etc.

Can we do anything to prevent it with the help of javascript/angularjs, so that our page will not crash?